# Cannot find Clear-WindowsAzureLog

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-diagnostics

There are several references to Clear-WindowsAzureLog, including one here - [Windows Azure - Cleaning Up The WADLogsTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905240/windows-azure-cleaning-up-the-wadlogstable)

However, I can't find it in the latest release of the Azure Powershell (https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell)

Has it been removed? Is there a replacement?